# Increasing Size of Legends in Jfree Chart

Tags: java

How to Increase the Size of The Legend Keys which displays colors. The Font Size is adjusted by `chart.getLegend().setItemFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12));`

but I couldnt find out the way how can I manage Size of the color Keys. My code is

```
plot.setInsets(new RectangleInsets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0));
                    plot.setToolTipGenerator(new StandardPieToolTipGenerator(
                         StandardPieToolTipGenerator.DEFAULT_SECTION_LABEL_FORMAT));
                    plot.setDirection(Rotation.CLOCKWISE);


                    List keys = dataset.getKeys();
                    int i=0;
                     for (Iterator it = keys.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                        Comparable key = (Comparable) it.next();
                        plot.setSectionPaint(key,requiredcol[i]);
                        //plot.setExplodePercent(key, 0.04);
                        i++;
                     }
                     // create a Ring Chart...
                     JFreeChart chart =  new JFreeChart(chartTitle, JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, showLegend);
                       chart.setPadding(new RectangleInsets(0,0,0,0));
                       chart.setBackgroundPaint(java.awt.Color.white);


                   if(showLegend){
                   chart.getLegend().setFrame(BlockBorder.NONE);
                   chart.getLegend().setPosition(RectangleEdge.RIGHT);
                   chart.getLegend().setItemFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
                   }
                   //chart.removeLegend();
                   // save it to an image   
                    try {
                        final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo(new StandardEntityCollection());
                        final File file1 = new File(chartDirectory + File.separator + chartFileName.toString().trim());
                        ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, width, height, info);
                        currentImageMap = ImageMapUtilities.getImageMap(chartFileName.toString(),info);
                         }
```

ALso my Key Size gets reflected by small amount by  `plot.setSectionOutlineStroke(new BasicStroke(3));`.. Please Help!

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDh4Z.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answers found [here](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=28433)
and [here](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=31535) to similar questions, I was able to achieve it in my project.

This is my Scala code:

```
plot.getRenderer().asInstanceOf[StackedBarRenderer].setBaseLegendShape(new Rectangle(30,30))
```

In Java this translates to:

```
((AbstractRenderer) plot.getRenderer()).setBaseLegendShape(new Rectangle(30,30));
```

The result is what I expected: the shape and size of the color keys is changed accordingly.